# best way to keep endpoints required by a service

Tags: java, spring-boot

Suppose i have a service that make multiple api calls to multiple micro services
Currently i am fetching all required endpoints from database and setting them as system property.
But i  want to remove this db call and at the same time externalize the same.
Can you please suggest me best ways to externalize these endpoints?

Answer (score 0):

In micro-service based architecture, *ideally* what you need is [service registry](https://microservices.io/patterns/service-registry.html) and [server side service discovery](https://microservices.io/patterns/server-side-discovery.html) pattern to tackle multiple service calls.

If you are sure that your api calls are never gonna change, then keeping it in `.properties` file make sense, but again if they change you have to re-deploy your service.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the API end points from a Directory which will have the latest API end points. This has to be a global DB or Directory. Try using JNDI.